# How To Create Two Column Page in HTML5 through Notepad++

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

Trying to make a two column page so I can have two columns of information. I cannot get it to work though. I have a large table that takes up half the page and is pushed to the left, but I cannot get the other part to go on the right! It just goes underneath. Please if you know how tell me. I have to do this for a school project! Here is my code:

```css
 .body {
 font-family: "Bookman Old Style";
 background:url('https://i.gifer.com/7sav.gif');
 color: white;
 }
   
 <!--backup    background-color: #D10F0F;-->
   
 .table {
 background-color: #B6B6B6;
 font-size: 17px;
 border-color: white;
 }
   
 .header {
 }
   
 .rowone {
 float: left;
    width: 50%;
 }
   
 .rowtwo:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
 float: right;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>My Typical Day</title>
 </head>
 <body class="body">
 <div class="header">
 <center>
    <!--Header-->
 <h1><u>My Typical Day</u></h1>
 <h4><u>By: Taylor Sloan</u></h4>
 </div>
    <!--End Of Header-->
 <center>
    <!--Table Start (ROW 1)-->
    <div class="rowone">
 <table border="2" bordercolor="white" class="table">
 <tr>
 <td><strong>Hour</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Class</strong></td>
 <td><strong>Teacher</strong></td>
 <td><strong>Image</strong></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>Spanish 2.5</td>
 <td>Córdoba</td>
 <td><!--TAKEN OUT--></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>Wood Technologies I</td>
 <td>Cortez</td>
    <td><!--TAKEN OUT--></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>Honors Geometry</td>
 <td>Alexander</td>
 <td><!--TAKEN OUT--></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>4</td>
 <td>Honors Biology</td>
 <td>Martens</td>
 <td><!--TAKEN OUT--></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>5</td>
 <td>Honors English Language Arts</td>
 <td>McCrossen</td>
 <td><!--TAKEN OUT--></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>6</td>
 <td>Physical Education</td>
 <td>Lowe</td>
 <td><!--TAKEN OUT--></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>7</td>
 <td>Web Design</td>
 <td>Foster</td>
 <td><!--TAKEN OUT--></td>
 </tr>
 <table>
 </div>
    <!--Table End-->
    <!--ROW2 STARTS-->
 <div class="rowtwo">
 <h3>My Top Three Favorite Books and Why</h3>
 <ol>
 <li>The Dragon Inside Series</li>
 </ol>
 </div>
 <h5><em>Email Me!</em></h5>
 </div>
 </center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Can anyone tell me what to do to fix it and attach a working version? I'm also doing this in Notepad++, not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make sure that your element tags are closed in the correct places, CENTER, DIV and TABLE tags all needed to be closed correctly.

Also, the CENTER tag is now deprecated and it is recommended that you use CSS to center your elements, like text-align: center

```css
body {
  font-family: "Bookman Old Style";
  background: url('https://i.gifer.com/7sav.gif');
  color: white;
}

<!--backup background-color: #D10F0F;
-->.table {
  background-color: #B6B6B6;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-color: white;
}

.header {}

.rowone {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.rowtwo:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <center>
    <!--Header-->
    <h1><u>My Typical Day</u></h1>
    <h4><u>By: Taylor Sloan</u></h4>
  </center>
</div>
<!--End Of Header-->
<center>
  <!--Table Start (ROW 1)-->
  <div class="rowone">
    <table border="2" bordercolor="white" class="table">
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Hour</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Class</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Teacher</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Image</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Spanish 2.5</td>
        <td>Córdoba</td>
        <td>
          <!--TAKEN OUT-->
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Wood Technologies I</td>
        <td>Cortez</td>
        <td>
          <!--TAKEN OUT-->
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Honors Geometry</td>
        <td>Alexander</td>
        <td>
          <!--TAKEN OUT-->
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Honors Biology</td>
        <td>Martens</td>
        <td>
          <!--TAKEN OUT-->
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Honors English Language Arts</td>
        <td>McCrossen</td>
        <td>
          <!--TAKEN OUT-->
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Physical Education</td>
        <td>Lowe</td>
        <td>
          <!--TAKEN OUT-->
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Web Design</td>
        <td>Foster</td>
        <td>
          <!--TAKEN OUT-->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!--Table End-->
  <!--ROW2 STARTS-->
  <div class="rowtwo">
    <h3>My Top Three Favorite Books and Why</h3>
    <ol>
      <li>The Dragon Inside Series</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h5><em>Email Me!</em></h5>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: You **really** should mention that `center` is obsolete and provide an alternative: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 0):

Div elements will display as "block" elements by default, which only allows one per line. The next block level element will appear below it.

Add this CSS rule to `.rowone` and `.rowtwo`: `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`

**Edit**: MichaelvE's answer is correct. Floating block level divs will allow two blocks to appear on the same line, much like an inline element. I missed the open tags when skimming over the code.